# Mask handling in tf.keras.Model with input shape does not match the specified one

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I recently encountered a problem when using TensorFlow 2.9.1. When I use an `tf.keras.layers.InputLayer`, if the masked input shape does not match the specified size, both the input and its mask can pass through the layer. However, if I wrap `tf.keras.layers.InputLayer` in a `tf.keras.Model`, when the masked input shape does not match the specified size, its `_keras_mask` disappear.

Please see the example below:

```py
import tensorflow as tf
print(f"TF version: {tf.__version__}")

def test_masking(m, exp_name = "test m"):
    print(exp_name)
    
    x1 = tf.random.uniform((5, 100, 64, 1))
    x1._keras_mask = tf.sequence_mask([50]*4+[100])
    print(x1.shape, x1._keras_mask.shape, m(x1).shape)
    print(m(x1)._keras_mask.shape)

    x2 = tf.random.uniform((5, 100, 64))
    x2._keras_mask = tf.sequence_mask([50]*4+[100])
    print(x2.shape, x2._keras_mask.shape, m(x2).shape)
    print(m(x2)._keras_mask.shape)
    
# Just an InputLayer
m1 = tf.keras.layers.InputLayer(input_shape=(None, 64, 1))

# InputLayer in tf.keras.Model
inp = tf.keras.Input([None, 64,  1])
out = tf.keras.layers.InputLayer(input_shape=(None, 64, 1))(inp)
m2 = tf.keras.Model(inp, out)

test_masking(m1, "test m1")
test_masking(m2, "test m2")
```

The outputs and error messages are:

```bash
TF version: 2.9.1
test m1
(5, 100, 64, 1) (5, 100) (5, 100, 64, 1)
(5, 100)
(5, 100, 64) (5, 100) (5, 100, 64)
(5, 100)
test m2
(5, 100, 64, 1) (5, 100) (5, 100, 64, 1)
(5, 100)
(5, 100, 64) (5, 100) (5, 100, 64, 1)
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
Input In [2], in <cell line: 26>()
     23 m2 = tf.keras.Model(inp, out)
     25 test_masking(m1, "test m1")
---> 26 test_masking(m2, "test m2")

Input In [2], in test_masking(m, exp_name)
     13 x2._keras_mask = tf.sequence_mask([50]*4+[100])
     14 print(x2.shape, x2._keras_mask.shape, m(x2).shape)
---> 15 print(m(x2)._keras_mask.shape)

File ~/miniforge3/envs/tf2/lib/python3.10/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py:446, in Tensor.__getattr__(self, name)
    437 if name in {"T", "astype", "ravel", "transpose", "reshape", "clip", "size",
    438             "tolist", "data"}:
    439   # TODO(wangpeng): Export the enable_numpy_behavior knob
    440   raise AttributeError(
    441       f"{type(self).__name__} object has no attribute '{name}'. " + """
    442     If you are looking for numpy-related methods, please run the following:
    443     from tensorflow.python.ops.numpy_ops import np_config
    444     np_config.enable_numpy_behavior()
    445   """)
--> 446 self.__getattribute__(name)

AttributeError: 'tensorflow.python.framework.ops.EagerTensor' object has no attribute '_keras_mask'
```

I am looking for answers for the following two questions:

1. Why aren't there any warnings or errors when the input shape does not match the one specified in `tf.keras.layers.InputLayer`?
2. Why does the input mask disappear if I wrap `tf.keras.layers.InputLayer` in a `tf.keras.Model`, when the input shape does not match the specified one? The mask can pass through `tf.keras.layers.InputLayer` even when the input shape does not match the specified one.

Comment: It is unclear what your issue is. The error message is very explicit.  You are calling `._keras_mask` on an object (`tf.keras.Model`) that doesn't have that attribute.

Comment: My question is, why `tf.keras.Model` does not have that attribute? The input tensor has the `_keras_mask` attribute, but it disappears in the output tensor.

Comment: @o-90 I updated the description. The function is not calling an `tf.keras.Model` object, it's the output tensor of the model object.